# Ruby: Quickest route from hash A to hash B

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash

I am new to ruby and looking for an elegant way to sort the following hash.

**Hash A:**

```
a = { :metric1 => {
          "Bob" =>10,
          "Jane" =>15,
          "Sally" =>20
      },                
      :metric2 => {  
          "Jane" =>15,
          "Bob" =>10,
          "Sally" =>10 
      },         
      :metric3 => {  
          "Bob" =>10,
          "Sally" =>10,
          "Jane" =>5
      }
    }
```

**Hash B:**

```
b = { "Bob" => {
        :metric1 =>10,
        :metric2 =>10,
        :metric3 =>10
      },
      "Jane" => {
        :metric1 =>15,
        :metric2 =>15,
        :metric3 =>5
      },
      "Sally" => {
        :metric1 =>20,
        :metric2 =>10,
        :metric3 =>10
      }
    }
```

Essentially I want an easy way to iterate this object to output a table like:

```
        Metric 1  Metric 2  Metric 3
Bob     10        20        20
Jane    15        15        5
Sally   20        10        10
```

Comment: shouldn't the values in "a" and "b" match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functional approach (assumes all people have the same metric keys):

```
names = a.values.first.keys
b = Hash[names.map do |name| 
  [name, Hash[a.map { |metric, values| [metric, values[person]] }]]
end]
```

[Edit] A second approach, proably more orthodox than my first attempt. It uses Facets (so it may look a bit cryptic for those unfamiliar the new abstractions it procides). However, it's easy if you check the output of each step:

```
triplets = a.flat_map { |metric, h| h.map { |name, value| [name, metric, value] } }
pairs_by_name = triplets.map_by { |name, metric, value| [name, [metric, value]] }
b = pairs_by_name.mash { |name, pairs| [name, pairs.to_h] }
```

Comment: @apneadiving: I was personally offended by that remark :-) updated with a second phrasing.

Comment: I don't have ree to test, but no problem with 1.8.7, no new magic used (so I guess ree also ok). I should add that Enumerable#mash comes from facets: http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html. Granted, the first snippet is a bit ugly, but the culprit is basically the horrible non-OOP Hash[...] constructor.

Comment: awesome, it's a pity I can't +1 once again ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd more simply do:

```
h = {}
a.each do |metric, hash|
  hash.each do |name, value|
    h[name] ||= {}
    h[name][metric] = value
  end
end
```

Comment: it looks like to_sym is creating :"Bob" as the pointer instead of just "Bob".... nevermind my mistake.

Comment: oops, yes and it was useless :)

Comment: +1, I won't argue that in this case a imperative loop is less verbose and slightly more clear than a functional one. Though, to be clear, `each` is still evil :-)

Comment: @tokland: should I be offended myself? ;)

Comment: @tokland For my edification, how evil is `each`? Evil memory-wise? or something else?

Comment: @MattDressel: It's not a problem of efficiency, it's conceptual. That sums up my opinion on the subject: http://www.slideshare.net/tokland/functional-programming-with-ruby-9975242 https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer with a more functional flavor.  It handles the case where some names only occur in some hashes -- let's say Sally only was only present for :metric3 -- albeit by putting nils in the result hash

```
metrics = a.keys
names = a.values.map { |v| v.keys }.flatten.uniq

names.inject({}) do |memo, name|
  memo[name] = metrics.inject({}) do |memo, metric|
    memo[metric] = a[metric][name]
    memo
  end
  memo
end
```